# Is the 'restrictions'/'guardrails' on dump access going to affect the Overflow Offline project?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I've generally been interested in the CSR aspect of Stack Overflow Inc. One of the initiatives that Stack Overflow Inc. was working on was the [Overflow Offline project](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/10/20/introducing-the-overflow-offline-project/).

As per your own media - it benefits prisoners training for their life after prison, scientists in remote locations  and schoolchildren in places with poor Internet access.

Considering the archives [Kiwix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiwix) is using are based on the dumps, is there potential impact from restricting access to the data dumps?

Comment: [The champion of the initiative](https://twitter.com/teresadg/status/1583117961526915073?cxt=HHwWgsDR5b7ZrvgrAAAA) is gone. Obviously, the remaining management don't care. Either about this, about us, or about the community in general.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that they considered *any* stakeholders other than themselves.

Comment: What is [CSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSR)? [Client-side rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page)? [Corporate social responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_social_responsibility)?

Comment: Learning from history is not fashionable, even if it is very much Stack Overflow's roots. [IMDb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMDb) (license. Stealing the contributors' data), [Yahoo Answers](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed) (no longer with us), [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) (now has erected paywalls around previously freely available answers (similar to ExpertsExchange). AI moderation bots of unspecified IQ. Probably not with us for much longer)), and [ExpertsExchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts_Exchange) (stealing the contributors' data)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum I suppose Corporate Social Responsibility...

Comment: It's weird that there's no post about Overflow Offline project from staff on MSE/MSO.